# Uncaught TypeError: this.model is not a constructor in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am new in Backbone.js. I just started a project with backbone.js. But i am faceing some issues. my model is :

```js
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

var Event = Backbone.Model.extend({
   urlRoot: '/event',
   idAttribute: 'eventID',
   defaults: {
    eventID: null
     , eventKind: null
     , eventTypeID: null
     , eventDate: null
    }
  });
  return Event;
});
```

Collection is :

```js
define([
   'jquery',
   'underscore',
   'backbone',
   '../newModels/event'
 ], function($, _, Backbone, Event){
 
 var event = new Event();
var Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({
 url: '/event',
 model: event,
 orderBy: "eventID",

});

return Events;

});
```

and my View is :

```js
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  '../newModels/event',
  '../newCollections/events',
  'text!templates/Template.html'
], function($, _, Backbone,Event,EventsCollection,Template){

 
 var sView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#contentView"),    
    render: function(){  
     var eventsCollection = new EventsCollection();
     var data = [];     
     eventsCollection.fetch({
   success: function(collection,response){
    alert("REST Service call was success");
    alert(JSON.stringify(collection.models));        
        })     
    }

  });

  return sView;
  
});
```

But when execute the eventsCollection.fetch() in render function, i am getting the following error :

> Uncaught TypeError: this.model is not a constructor
>       at F.d._prepareModel (backbone-min.js:24)
>       at F.d.add (backbone-min.js:19)

Please help me to find out the issue/my mistakes in coding. Every help will be appreciable.

Comment: Your collection should say `model: Event`, a collection's `model` should be a "class", not an instance: ["Override this property to specify the model class that the collection contains."](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model)

Comment: Thank, Its works